# Knockout - Creating Model from existing JSON data for Select All checkbox list

Tags: json, knockout.js, faceted-search

That's a pretty long winded statement.

I'm building a faceted search which implements WebAPI in .Net and utilizes Knockout on the front end. My search response includes two lists of objects, the Resources (object with data for presentation) and Resource Facets (array of strings).

`\"ResourceFacets\": [\r\n    \"Book\",\r\n    \"Video\",\r\n    \"DVD\",\r\n    \"eBook\",\r\n    \"Audio\"\r\n  ]\r\n}"`

My ViewModel contains both the facets and the resources along with a presentation object to handle a custom row count:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.facets = ko.observableArray(results.ResourceFacets);
    this.resources = ko.observableArray(results.ResourceResults);

    this.resourceRows = ko.computed(function() {
        var rows = [],
            rowIndex = 0,
            itemsPerRow = 2;

        var resourceList = this.resources();

        for (var index = 0; index < resourceList.length; index++) {
            if (!rows[rowIndex]) {
                rows[rowIndex] = [];
            }

            rows[rowIndex].push(resourceList[index]);

            if (rows[rowIndex].length == itemsPerRow) {
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }

        return rows;
    });
};
```

This allowed me to create a dynamic list of checkboxes to handle the facets and also display the resource results. What I'm trying to do now is add a Select All checkbox which will, by default, select all the boxes. From other examples I've seen, my understanding is that I need an observable property, something like "Selected", on that ResourceFacet. I just feel like that is too much that the API needs to know about my presentation.

So my question is how can I avoid having to add a "selected" bool value to the ResourceFacets but still be able to select all checkboxes or deselect the "All" checkbox when a user deselects a facet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the list of booleans necessary to track the selection on a separate member of your view model, in addition to `facets` and `resources`. Just create a new observableArray of booleans of the same size of `facets` and bind those values to the checkboxes.

Another solution is to create the objects necessary to bind the checkboxes on the fly, based on `results.ResourceFacets`, keeping your API clean. For example:

```
var realModel = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.ResourceFacets; i++) {
    realModel.push({ name: results.ResourceFacets[i], chkBoxVal: ko.observable(false) });
}
this.facets = ko.observableArray(realModel);
```